# Android Button Height (programmatically)

Tags: android, button, layout

How to set button height less then 30px? I tried the next:

---

[image]

---

1. setHeight(30); (set 150 is working, but set 30 is not)
2. setPadding(0,-20,0,-20); (width is changes, height is not)
3. LinearLayout.LayoutParams (set 150 is working, but set 30 is not)
4. new Button(this, null, android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall); - effects only on button text

---

[image]

---

```
Button mainButton = new Button(this);
mainButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
mainButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
l.addView(mainButton);
```

[image]

---

```
SmallButton mainButton = new SmallButton(this);
        mainButton.setText(s);
        mainButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_drawable);
        mainButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,FlowLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        l.addView(mainButton);

public class SmallButton extends Button {

public SmallButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SmallButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SmallButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, 35));
}

 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0,-5);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

}

[image]

I have a Shape drawable with gradient for my background as I don't know the exact width. I also tried to setup its height. Is it possible to make button wrap it text only?

**EDIT:** 
The problem is solved with the use of TextView instead of the Button. Ofcourse if you are not using the specific/overriden things in Button.class.

Comment: if you want the button height to wrap its text only , simply set padding to 0 , and use `android:layout_height = "wrap_content"` , it will wrap the height in function with the content of your button

Comment: I edited my question. I tried it and it does not work. It effects only only width but not a height.

Comment: why you don't add your button from your xml layout ? ? and what is the parent of your buttons and its layout params ?

Comment: I can't add buttons from xml because they are randomly generated. Parent layout is [FlowLayout](http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/) with params: height-wrap_content, widht-match_parent. I also tried the same with LinearLayout, didn't help either (I don't think that parent layout effects).

Comment: but its layout params may effects :), if you are setting some margin and padding to your FlowLayout and a width or height to a fixed size. add the full code of generating the parent and the buttons

Answer (score 12):

There are two parameters. 
Button.setMinimumHeight() and Button.setMinHeight(). Ensure that both of them are set to value "0".

Comment: That's really goofy, but indeed, setting both did the job in my project.

Comment: I was having no success in reducing button height using setMinHeight() but this fixed it. Why have one method to set min height when you can have two :-)

Answer (score 1):

Every `View` in Android can have a minimum width and height set for them. A `Button` will set these depending on the style it is using on the device it is using.

However, this can be overridden in the xml for the button:

```
android:minHeight="0dip"
android:minWidth="0dip"
```

<strike>As @Sudar Nimalan points out, this is related to the background of the button. If you don't wish to create your own button class, you can simply set the background to something smaller. Try setting the background to a solid colour, or create your own background for it.</strike>

Comment: Setting background to solid or drawable background didn't help. That will work with ImageButton, but not with a button.

Comment: Good point - it changes the width but not the height. Any reason why you don't define a 9 part png as the background and use an ImageButton? Answer updated.

Comment: Button should contain the text, that's why I can't define 9 patch drawable. MinHeight, MaxHeight for 150 works perfect, but for 30 - don't work, it sets 50. So it's some minimum height and I've no idea how to override it.

Comment: so `button.setMinHeight(0)` doesn't shrink to just wrap the text?

Comment: button.setMinHeight(0) - does not have effect, button.setMinHeight(30) - does not have effect; button.setMinHeight(150); - sets the height of the button to 150dp.

Comment: Yes, but in the code above you are forcing the button to have a minimum height of 35, which will override this. Try _not_ overriding onMeasure with the minimum height set to 0.

Comment: obviously, `setHeight` will be limited to the default minimum height of a Button. But `setMinimumHeight` should override this. Could you post the code where you are setting all these things? Given what you say, there must be more that you've got so far in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Button mainButton = new Button(sm);
mainButton.setText(s);
mainButton.setMinHeight(15);l.addView(mainButton);

Comment: I wonder if you need to do the setMinimumHeight() as late as possible in the sequence?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mainButton.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, This causes due the default background drawable minimum height size, you can sent a empty background or color and test these scenarios.

If you want to change the height with default drawable, you can create your Custom Button extending the Button class and override on onMeasure and  onDraw etc.

override the onDraw to shift the default button drawing:

```
onDraw(canvas){
     canvas.save();
     canvas.translate(0,value to shift);
     super.onDraw(canves);
     canvas.restore();
}


@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
         super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec,MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, 35));
    }
```

Comment: Overridden onMeasure -  this.setMeasuredDimension(this.getMeasuredWidth(), 40); - cuts the bottom and cuts button text because the text still in the middle of the button. setGravity(center/top) didn't help.

Comment: then override the onDraw to shift the drawing up as give above in answer.

Comment: It cuts the text and leaves the empty space under the bottom of drawable. Sometimes it shift the text into another view.

Comment: could you try to override onMeasure as given. because text drawing to done by TextView, the supper class of Button

Comment: Sure, but nothing changes.

Comment: I tested now it worked. Can you add your full class CutomeButton and new CustomButton etc..